# Query of the YouTube Analyics API doesn't return any data for the last 3 days

Tags: youtube-api, google-apis-explorer, youtube-analytics-api

Today is Nov 24th, 2020. I'm using this API:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query`.

I set the query parameters as:

- `endDate=2020-11-24`  (today),
- `startDate=2020-11-20` (4 days ago),
- `ids=channel==MINE`,
- `dimensions=day`,
- `sort=day`,
- `metrics=views`.

This is what I get in return:

```json
    {
      "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
      "columnHeaders": [
        {
          "name": "day",
          "columnType": "DIMENSION",
          "dataType": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "name": "views",
          "columnType": "METRIC",
          "dataType": "INTEGER"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "2020-11-20",
          20
        ],
        [
          "2020-11-21",
          23
        ]
      ]
    }
```

As you can see, the data is missing for the dates 2020-11-22, 2020-11-23, and 2020-11-24.

Comment: I'd suggest to report this directly to Google, via its [issue tracker web site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Data isn't available for past two days.

Comment: @SamLehman What do you mean by that? Could you point to any documentation entry that talks about that?

Comment: @bmiselis not sure about any docs, but just from personal experience.